# How to estimate additional variables in a df by group in R?

Tags: r

I have a data frame, consisting of stand ID, Treatment type, revision, and tree diameter. I want to estimate an additional variable - Quadratic mean diameter (and other variables) for every stand, revision and treatment separately, using a function: sqrt(sum(dia^2)/n).

An example of my dataset:

ID     Rev Treat   dia

1523    1   A   7.549834

1523    1   A   4.500000

1523    1   B   1.500000

1523    1   B   2.949576

1523    2   A   6.348228

1523    2   A   2.900000

1523    2   B   3.400000

1523    2   B   6.449806

1545    1   A   2.349468

1545    1   A   5.249762

1545    1   B   6.249800

1545    1   B   8.748714

1545    2   A   0.100000

1523    2   A   0.100000

1523    2   B   3.200000

1523    2   B   3.200000

So, basically what I want to do is have an estimate of Dq for 1) Stand 1523, Rev 1, Treat A; 2) 1) Stand 1523, Rev 1, Treat B; 3) Stand 1523, Rev 2, Treat A and so on.

My dataset is much larger, consisting of 4 treatments, 6 revisions and 8 stands. Making a loop would be one option I guess, but there must be an easier way how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
data.df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Rev, Treat) %>% 
  summarise(quadratic_mean_diameter = sqrt(sum(dia^2)/length(dia)))
```